# SystemModStamp and LastModifiedDate contains different date

Tags: sobject, automated-process, systemmodstamp

I have checked and part of my records contains different date in that fields. Systemmodstamp is 9.10 and LastModifiedDate is 5.10. I thought that systemmodstamp is different because of automated process, but i have triggered it and now both fields contains the same value. So how can they contain different values?

Comment: Do you have some rollup fields, or a lookup that has a "set null" deletion constraint in this record?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387261&type=1 does this answer your question?

Comment: @PhilW no, nothing like that. I have formula, but i checked and it doesnt change systemmodstamp

Comment: @AnkaiahBandi I dont think so. I have added new picklist values, but it doesnt change anything. No more changes.

Comment: Some Salesforce internal backend processes will also update 'SystemModstamp,' as 'SystemModstamp' is used internally to signal that a record, or related data, may have changed - and that internal processes may need to synchronize themselves to the new record data.